# Can someone give a picture to visualize and elucidate the celebrated rhyme of Richardson about turbulence?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, turbulence, vortex

Richardson's celebrated rhyme is below:

> Big whorls have little whorls,
> which feed on their velocity,
> and little whorls have lesser whorls,
> and so on to viscosity.
>
> (Lewis F. Richardson, 1920)

I read the rhyme and have no picture in my mind, I wonder what picture and concept the Richardson wanted to express. Can you give me a picture about this rhyme?

Comment: see images here https://chsharrison.wordpress.com/2018/06/19/a-poem-about-ocean-turbulence/

Comment: Note that the poem is also an allusion to a more famous one about fleas:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphonaptera_(poem)

Answer (score 2):

These rhymes are usually referred to the concept of **energy cascade**, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_cascade, usually interpreted in the domain of wavelength.

Historically, it was thought that large coherent structures (whatever they are) associated with large wavelengths transfer  energy to structures with smaller wavelengths, and so on in a the energy cascade, down towards the so called Kolmogorov turbulent scale, where viscous dissipation dominates.

This picture of mono-directional energy cascade is not accepted anymore, because it can occur that energy is transferred from smaller to larger scales

Answer (score 1):

Richardson was probably familiar with the transition of from laminar flow to turbulence in smoke.
[image]

and vortex shedding as you move objects through a fluid.

[image]

These days there is a lot of [simulation and comparison to experiment] that can show some fractal like behavior more clearly[3](https://fyfluiddynamics.com/2012/06/these-images-from-a-numerical-simulation-of-a/).

[image]

Comment: 1 do you think the smoke picture & Karman vortex street picture can illustrate the rhyme? it's not obvious for me  2 do you think the core of the rhyme is fractal?

Comment: The poem was written in 1922, the word fractal is from the 1970s, but it doesn’t mean that people were not thinking of things as being similar on different length scales. Certainly smoke and smoke rings and turbulence were being observed and discussed. The vortex shedding is a nice example of what can be seen, but Richardson was interested in convection and the weather. So sure why not.

Comment: Apparently part of the fun Richardson was having with the poem was that it was a play on Jonathan Swifts poem about fleas.  https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3697

Answer (score 1):

There is a beautiful experiment by McKeow et al. "The Emergence of Small Scales in Vortex Ring Csllisions", video in the link [1]. You can also check their paper "Cascade leading to the emergence of small structures in vortex ring collisions", link [2].

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z099yZzQik

[2] https://journals.aps.org/prfluids/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.3.124702?casa_token=ovtIj0OK2w4AAAAA%3A2VslBIo0y9uLItNDYDu0wU-MaxRf6SiJUpPIsZMBh_rHIRFcsmSQGAvrYeSG1jhEweiGV1x5udY3p9aa